# NS Timer to update textField

Tags: cocoa, nstimer

Thanks for the help.

I have a textField that I want to update according to the following time increments:

[textField setStringValue:@"Audio 1"]; 7sec.

[textField setStringValue:@""]; 3sec.

[textField setStringValue:@"Audio 2"]; 7sec.

I need the above to loop cumulatively for a total of 5 min.

Any guidance on how to set up NSTimer(s) to accomplish this?

Again - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create the timer to fire every second.
- Create a counter variable, set it to 600 and decrement it in the timer action. Stop the timer – or whatever you need to do – when the counter reaches zero.
- Create two arrays, one with the string values and the other with the durations.
- Create a second counter variable for the durations.
- Create an index variable and set it to 0.
- Get the string value and duration at the given index.
- Set the second counter to the duration and assign the string value to the text field.
- In the timer action decrement also the second counter. If it's 0 increment the index, if the index is equal to the number of items in the array set the index to 0.
- Goto to the step "Get the string value and duration at..."